# Generic PostgreSQL Exception with Android Studio

Tags: postgresql, java, exception, android

I'm trying to connect to a database via android studio but with poor results.

In my onCreate () I have the following code which theoretically shouldn't be wrong...

```
try {

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM shopping_list");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        records += resultSet.getString(1);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also added the file `postgresql-42.2.19.jar` to the lib folder but anyway I also tried with the classic `mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar` and nothing .

I also added the dependencies
to the manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
and to build.grandle
`implementation files('libs/postgresql-42.2.19.jar')`

The exception it catches is the following

```
W/System.err: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at com.example.grecosapp.activity_manager.ShoppingListActivity.onCreate(ShoppingListActivity.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:235)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:229)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: I tried just now and i have the same problem in Connection line.

Answer (score 0):

Walfrat has nailed the actual cause of your problem with their comment - network on main thread - but I'm going to post a frame challenge answer.

While it might be possible to get an Android application to talk directly to a database over the network, you do not want to do this. Unless the application is going to be for literally one single user, this is a bad idea. The database user and password will be distributed to all the users of your app and that is an invite for any of them to log into your database from a Postgres client and have a look around, modify data, delete things - basically any of the `GRANT` powers* you have given that database user so that the app can function.

A more modern way of providing remote access to an app would be to write a server side program that goes along with your app. This is usually a REST API or a GraphQL server these days. This service will then have the database connection.

This way, your users will create accounts with your service (users being held in a database table, not database users), they can authenticate against it and then perform actions. This back-end service can then provide access control and present only the data associated with this user to them and allow them to only modify their data.

*maybe up to altering the schema or `DROP`ping tables. You did create the schema with a different user to the one that will be accessing and modifying the data, yes?